# Docker-compose volume set host Path

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I've created a simple example where i'm trying to achive a simple task. I need to mount a specific folder inside my container to a specific folder on the host machine.

The dockerfile that create the image i use in my docker-compose is the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY ./file.txt /vol/file.txt
```

In this folder, on the container side, i copy a file called `file.txt`, and i need this behaviour on the host machine:

- If the Host machine folder is empty or not exising or the file is missing, i need to copy inside that the `file.txt` file.
- If the Host machine folder has already a file with that name, the file is preserved and not overriden.

This is exactly what happens when `volume` is used inside docker-compose. The problem with this is that you can't choose the folder on the host machine, but you can simply assign to the volume a name and Docker will create it inside one of his folders.

Instead using `mount point` lets you choose the folder on the host machine, but here the behaviour is different: even if the folder on the host machine is empty or not exising, the file `file.txt` is deleted on the container.

A pratical example of this is a common application distributed with docker. I start from a dotnet image and copy inside it my application that will start on container load. Inside this application i have a configuration file that i need to preserve on image updates, so i need to copy it on Host machine, and this file has to be editable by the user that use the host machine, so it can't be on a subfolder of docker installation with a random name.

There's a way to achieve this?

Comment: seems to me like you are just approaching the problem from the wrong angle? why are you trying to build an image of a container which already has "context". why not just build the image with that file located elsewhere on disk & use an entrypoint script to test whether or not to copy it to the desired location (using bash)

Comment: If the main goal of your application is interacting with host-system files like this, an isolation layer like Docker might not be the packaging mechanism you want.  If Docker weren't involved then you can just use normal file I/O and this isn't a problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze i've added an example of why i need that behaviour.